# Exception thrown when importing bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I scaffolded a new app with 'rails new'

and added the bootstrap gem `gem 'bootstrap'` to the Gemfile

did `gem install bootstrap` & `bundle install`

Added `@import 'bootstrap'` to `application.scss`

Now I get this error

[image]

I have nodeJs 8 installed

Edit: line 8 in the html file

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

I tried making it applicaition.scss, no luck

Comment: Please post the file in question.

Comment: Did you run `gem install bootstrap-sass`?

Answer (score 1):

Using

`gem 'execjs'`

instead of

`gem 'ducktape'`

as the JavaScript runtime seemed to fix it. I have no clue why though